# Count number of rows in a dataframe having different number of rows for each column

Tags: r, dataframe, count, rows

I am doing statistical analysis of some genes in R. The dataframe that contain genes have different number of rows for each column and I want to count the number of rows belonging to each column.

I have tried:

`sum(!is.na(mydata$"column_name")))`

as well as:

`NROW(mydata$"column_name")`

The above code gives 334 which is the length of the longest column. How can I count the "actual" number of rows (no. of observations) for each column?
Following is an image of how the dataframe look like:
https://ibb.co/mhRgVqx

Comment: Hey @user10944199, welcome to SO. It would be nice for this question and future ones you provide some reprodutible example.

Comment: Hey :) Thanks! I will definitely do it next time if I need some help. I am a new user to SO, so doesn't know much about how to upload and link files yet :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the absence of a reproductive example I can suppose that the NULL cells on the dataframe are in reality an empty string - "".

Give a try, adapting this solution:

```
sum(mydata$"column_name"!= "")
```